# Как распараллелить git merge?

Tags: git

Всем привет.
У нас есть git-овая репа, в репе много файлов.
Изредка приходится доливать туда изменения "снаружи".
В итоге получается, что при выполнении git merge origin/branch_with_new_code_snaruji образуется дофигища конфликтов.
Приходится в одиночку на локальной тачке резолвить все конфликты и потом делать git push.

Вопрос: есть ли в гите какой-нибудь хитрый способ распараллелить этот процесс?
Может можно запушить код вместе со всеми конфликтами, а потом "каждый хватает файл, резолвит конфликт, пушит"?
Или какие-то другие неочевидные способы?
Хочется, чтобы несколько человек одновременно резолвили конфликты одного merge-а одной ветки, на разных машинах одновременно (разные файлы у разных людей).

Comment: Нет. Но если это регулярная проблема, то у вас как-то неправильно процесс выстроен. Либо кодовая база реально огромная

Comment: Не очень. Всего 1М файлов.

Comment: 1. [получаете список файлов с конфликтами](https://stackoverflow.com/q/501407/4827341). 2. распределяете файлы по разработчикам. 3. они вносят изменения в `origin/branch_with_new_code_snaruji` (или в промежуточную, если данную ветку нельзя трогать), позволяющие избежать конфликта. 4. делаете *merge* уже без конфликтов.

Comment: немного другой путь вместо третьего и четвёртого пункта: [каждый разработчик вливает только один (или больше) файл](https://stackoverflow.com/q/449541/4827341).

Comment: Проект открытый? Интересно было бы глянуть на это. `Изредка приходится доливать туда изменения "снаружи".` - значит делайте вливания чаще. Можно "подливать" изменения прямо в dev-ветку, каждый день, например, тогда при мерже ... не будет конфликтов.

Comment: Проект закрытый :(